# How to solve VScode UnsupportedClassVersionError?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

#### Problem

When i run my HelloWorld, it returns:

> "java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: HelloWorld has been compiled
>   by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version
>   52.65535), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 "

How do I solve this problem?

#### Screenshot

[image]

#### Code

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("123");
    }
}
```

Comment: What command are you using to compile & run with?

Answer (score 6):

The issue is connected with Java Debugger extension. I had the same problem and it has been logged in issue log: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/555

Problem is only with single file applications like HelloWorld. It is ok if you run maven project.

Medsonk's instruction worked for me: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/555#issuecomment-478464496

> *summary:
>
>   1. make sure uninstall jdk8 clean
>
>   2. install jdk11
>
>   3. add "vmArgs": "--enable-preview" in launch.json
>
>   4. F1, "Java: Clean ……" and "Java: Force ……"
>
>   5. run standalone file again*

Comment: Already fixed in extension **Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat** [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java)

Comment: Just installed the latest VSCode and Java extention, ran into the same problem; Adding "vmArgs": "--enable-preview" in launch.json > configuration, fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall your old Java version.
2. Update JDK Development Kit https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads
3. Install the new Java version.

It's work for me (I'm using Windows).

Answer (score -2):

My situation is version conflict between java and javac on Ubuntu;
just run this code:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```