# Cannot run/compile java program with VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, ide, adoptopenjdk

When i am hitting f5 i get this text in debug window

```
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class Hello
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Hello (class file version 52.65535) was compiled with preview features that are unsupported. This version of the Java Runtime only recognizes preview features for class file version 56.65535
```

javac -version shows

```
javac 12
```

java -version

```
openjdk version "12" 2019-03-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 12+33)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 12+33, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Code that i am trying to compile

```java
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] agrs)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

PATH,JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME are set properly.
Debug add-on installed.
I can compile and run the same code in InteliJ IDEA or using java (file), javac (file) and it will work fine but i don't know why it does not work on vscode.

Comment: What package are you using in VSCode to debug your java code?

Comment: Also you made a typo in your text. You said `String[] agrs` when you meant to type `String[] args`

Comment: Seems like a bug in the debugger extension. Very similar Q a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55443351 (doesn't seem to be a dupe though, as the error messages are different) You could also try updating the extension.

Comment: @DylanRiley https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-debug

Comment: @JornVernee Extension and VSCode is latest version

Comment: Looks like the fix is in https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java version 0.42.1 according to https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/555#issuecomment-478825650 i.e. a dependency of the extension you linked.

Comment: @JornVernee This fix didn't worked for me, but solution in link that you posted previously helped, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@JornVernee send link to other question, it helped
[Link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55443351/how-to-solve-vscode-unsupportedclassversionerror)

> summary:
>
> 1. make sure uninstall jdk8 clean
> 2. install jdk11
> 3. add "vmArgs": "--enable-preview" in launch.json
> 4. F1, "Java: Clean ……" and "Java: Force ……"
> 5. run standalone file again